# Why is the SqlConnection with Textbox not working?

Tags: c#

I'm using this code for connection string:

```
namespace TransInsert
{
  public partial class Form1: Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Initial Catalog=database;user ID=sa;Password=xxxx");

    private void TextBox1.Text_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
  }
}
```

I place it under IntializeCompoment and I get error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'TransInsert.Form1.textBox1'

Comment: probably you do this in Initializer or in static method. Provide us with more of your code.

Comment: this wouldn't cause that

Comment: Youre doing this in completely the wrong place for a start. You are trying to pass a value outside of any method or event that could be triggered to give the connection string a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot set connection string using text box outside the event.you can use connection string in form_load event or button_click event like below

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlConnection con;
        con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=" + textBox1.Text + ";Initial Catalog=DBName;user ID=sa;Password=yourpassword");
        con.Open();
    }
```

Comment: So i was run my SqlConnection in wrong place thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

You can't initialize an instance variable (`con`) with another instance variable (`textBox1`).

In many cases it doesn't even really make sense to hold a reference to a database connection as an instance variable. Opening connections is cheap due to connection pooling, you can open one whenever you need and close it when you're done, and you'll be golden.

Do something like this when you need to pull data from your database:

```
void Foo()
{
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection("..."))
    {
        conn.Open();

        // then read about how to use ADO.NET
    }
}
```

Also, read about the `using` block and why it's a good idea.

Bonus chatter: *injection on connection strings is a thing*, be sure to check user input instead of blindingly incorporating it in your connection string.

Comment: I want to choose from a combobox which connection i want to open

Comment: @user6894907 then you want to make sure the control is not editable.