# Sql Connection to Class

Tags: c#

I want create a class which it will include my sql connection.Then in my form using this class in my connections:

Class Name is Connections

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public class Connections
{
    protected SqlConnection con;

     protected override void Main()
     {
       con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.100, 1433;Initial Catalog=database;user ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx");
    }
}
}
```

Also in My form

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Connections
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        //rest of my code
    }
}
}
```

But I get Error WindowsFormsApplication1.Connections.Main()': no suitable method found to override

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25816609/checking-user-name-or-user-email-already-exists/25817145#25817145. Check the accepted answer.

Comment: A connection is trivial to create and ought to be closed and disposed of when you finish using it.  So a "helper" class will likely do more harm than good,

Comment: This is worse than your [previous attempt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793098/). You need to understand what the code you write does, simply making random changes in the hope it will compile does not work, please get a book or follow an online tutorial.

Comment: I want to make a public connection inside my form: and then everywhere which i will use con.open(); to read from this public connection.PLS HELP ME.Should i use something like that?public void Connection()
        {
            myConnection = new SqlConnection("MySqlConnection");
            //myConnection.Open();
        }

Comment: No, you should create your connection in the Form_Load event, like in the answer you accepted [the previous time you asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39793776/22437).

Comment: look at that connections class - it is one (1) line of code.  You dont need a helper class for that.  Its a bad idea incorrectly implemented

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the SqlConnection with Textbox not working?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39793098/why-is-the-sqlconnection-with-textbox-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Your class `Connections` doesn't inherit from anything that contains a definition of `Main` and so the `override` attribute is inapplicable.

You should place your initialization code in your constructor:

```
public Connections()
{
    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.100, 1433;Initial Catalog=database;user ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx");
}
```

Main functions are for classes that are *run*. A class named Connections is more likely to be a utility class, so it doesn't make sense to have a Main function in it.

Comment: I get error Inconsistent accessibility: base class 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Connections' is less accessible than class 'WindowsFormsApplication1.Form1'

Comment: You shouldn't inherit `Form1` from `Connections`. Inheritance should follow an IS A pattern. A "Form1" is not an example of a "Connections", it is something that *uses* connections to accomplish its job. That indicates a composition relationship - your Form1 should have a reference to an instance of `Connections` and then call it as needed.

Comment: Can you write me the full code which i should use?In class and in my form

Comment: It's not hard. Just make `Connections` a class with a constructor as I indicated, then declare a field on class `Form1` of type `Connections` (`Connections myConnections;`), and in your `Form1` constructor (or its Main function if you have one) put `myConnections = new Connections();` to set it equal to a new instance of the class.

Comment: Could you give me an example?>